# Printing into a pop-up, instead on main window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, alert

I have this function which shows all my articles titles from 'Articles' database.

```
function show()
{
    database();

    $sql = "SELECT title FROM `Articles`";

    $titleSql = mysql_query( $sql ) or die("Could not select articles:");

    $html = '<html><body><div class="container"><h2>Basic List Group</h2><ul class="list-group">';

    while ($title = mysql_fetch_array($titleSql)) {
        $html .= '<li class="list-group-item">'.$title["title"].'</li>';
    }

    $html .= '</ul></div></body></html>';

    echo $html;
//  die("Functie terminata cu succes! :)");
 //   die(json_encode(array("mesaj" => "Entered data successfully ")));

}
```

This is the function in javascript.

```
function show()
    {
        var n = $('#show').val()
        $.post("functions.php", {show:n}).done(function(mesaj){
            alert(mesaj);
        });
    }
```

PROBLEM: because of the alert(mesaj), it shows the string $html into a pop-up, not on my main window, as I wish! 
HOW can I modify my functions so the articles list will show on m window?

Comment: when you return `html` you will get it as `mesaj` on `done` and the same you are displaying it in `alert`! what's wrong here??

Answer (score 4):

you have to give a container id to which it will set the data. Bellow i put it in document.

```
function show()
    {
        var n = $('#show').val()
        $.post("functions.php", {show:n}).done(function(mesaj){
            $(document).html(mesaj);
        });
    }
```

Comment: @aman, it worked with document.write(mesaj);

Is there a way of writing the message "mesaj" into a different html page? (to set a href)

Comment: what exactly what you want? You want to set href on the same page?

Comment: "mesaj" message is actually the content of a html page.
When I click the "SHOW" button on my index.php page, it shows me the message hold in "mesaj", but still in index.php. 
What I want is that when I click on the "SHOW" button on my index.php it shows me the content of the message into another php page, named - for eg - content.php. I want to set the href.